# Syntax to convert a string to a secure powershell inside of ASP/c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, powershell

I'm trying to run the new-mailbox command inside of an asp/c# webpage and I get the following message

> Additional information: Cannot process argument transformation on
>   parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the "(ConvertTo-SecureString
>   -String P@ssword1 -AsPlainText -Force)" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".

An example of command I am running is:

```
new-mailbox -UserPrincipalName "name@name.com" -Database "db033" -DisplayName "last, first" -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "P@ssw0rd1" -AsPlainText -Force) -FirstName "first" -LastName "last" -OrganizationalUnit "name.com/groups/grp/users" -PrimarySmtpAddress "first.last@name.com" -Alias "first.last" -Name "last, first""
```

Which works inside of Exchange powershell, but fails in ASP with the error message above when using a runspace and pipeline. I believe I have a syntax error, but am not sure. If my c# exchange powershell function is required, I can post that too, but it has worked with many other exchange functions, which is why I believe this is syntax related because of the 2 languages?

```cs
private List<string> runExchangeShell(string rootCommand, List<string> parameters, string module)
{
    Collection<PSObject> psobjs;
    //string result;
    SecureString PSpwd = new SecureString();
    PSpwd = convertToSecureString(PSPassword);
    PSCredential ExchangeCredential = new PSCredential(PSDomain + @"\" + PSUsername, PSpwd);
    WSManConnectionInfo connectionInfo = new WSManConnectionInfo(new Uri("[servername]/powershell"), " [servername] /powershell/Microsoft.Exchange", ExchangeCredential);
    connectionInfo.AuthenticationMechanism = AuthenticationMechanism.Kerberos; //.Basic;
    List<string> returnValue = new List<string>();
    using (Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(connectionInfo))
    {
        Pipeline pipeLine = runspace.CreatePipeline();
        Command myCommand = new Command(rootCommand);
        if (parameters != null)
        {
            foreach (string parameter in parameters)
            {
                string[] parameterSplit = parameter.Split('|');
                myCommand.Parameters.Add(parameterSplit[0], parameterSplit[1]);
            }

            runspace.Open();

            pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);

            Collection<PSObject> commandResults = pipeLine.Invoke();

            PSMemberInfoCollection<PSPropertyInfo> results = null;
            foreach (PSObject cmdlet in commandResults)
            {
                string cmdletName = cmdlet.BaseObject.ToString();
                results = cmdlet.Properties;
            }

            foreach (PSPropertyInfo result in results)
            {
                returnValue.Add(result.Name + "|" + result.Value);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            runspace.Open();

            pipeLine.Commands.Add(myCommand);
            Collection<PSObject> commandResults = new Collection<PSObject>();
            try
            {
                commandResults = pipeLine.Invoke();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }

            foreach (PSObject result in commandResults)
            {
                returnValue.Add(result.ToString());
            }
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

edit:

I've also tried this

I've also tried this above 'myCommand' that would use $pw

```
Command initializeVariable = new Command("Set-Variable");   
initializeVariable.Parameters.Add("name", "pw"); 
initializeVariable.Parameters.Add("value", "ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'P@ssw0rd1' -AsPlainText -Force");
```

And it tells me ?? An exception of type

> 'System.Management.Automation.RemoteException' occurred in
>   ASPNETTemplate.dll but was not handled in user code Additional
>   information: The term 'Set-Variable' is not recognized as the name of
>   a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: You haven't posted enough information.  How are you passing information to the runspace/etc?  Your syntax in your question is the correct way to handle that as-is.

Comment: The function has been added as an edit, with server names removed.

I call it like this:

runExchangeShell(rootCommand, parameters, "exchange");

Comment: Added another code example in the original post

Comment: So you're trying to initiate a WSMAN connection manually and using Kerberos to do so?  Doesn't the asp.net site run as an AppPool?

Comment: Yes it does run as an app pool.

I'm able to get it to work if I run it as a script and pass it as a single string like this

string script = @"$session = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'http://[server]/powershell'; import-pssession $session -AllowClobber; set-adserversettings -viewentireforest $true; Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned; $pw = '" + password + "'; $securePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $pw -Force; new-mailbox -UserPrincipalName '" + userPrincipalName + "' ...

Comment: private string runExchangeShellScript(string scriptText)
        {                       
                      Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();
            runspace.Open();
            Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
           
            pipeline.Commands.AddScript(scriptText);
            RunspaceInvoke runSpaceInvoker = new RunspaceInvoke(runspace);
            runSpaceInvoker.Invoke("Set-ExecutionPolicy bypass");

            Collection<PSObject> results = null;
                         results = pipeline.Invoke();
                   }

Comment: Running it as a script is using your impersonation, authenticating with Kerberos.  The AppPool runs as a virtual system user, so it's actually trying to authenticate with the machine account.

Comment: Sorry for the 3rd comment.

When I use the code above, it now gives me a registry error saying Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied. 

So if I can get past that, this might work? :/

Comment: @theincorrigible, so how can I get the script to run with the user that is logged into the webpage? Or use am authenticated account on behalf of the logged in user with the script code?